# Stateless ejb not getting destroyed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a REST interface for development purposes which sports a stateless EJB. It in turn injects another stateless EJB. It was my understanding that a stateless EJB is destroyed instead of passivated and reconstructed every time an instance is needed.

Using this logic I added a @PostConstruct (to both the REST and the other stateless ejb) but both are only called once (deduced from logging). Repeated calls to the REST layer will reuse the same bean (and its state!) instead of creating a new one.

What are the possible reasons that the stateless beans are not getting destroyed? Or have I misinterpreted the lifecycle of a stateless ejb?

**EDIT**: the "state" I'm referring to is a temporary cache the bean constructs to speed up execution. Perhaps a poor choice of words :)

**EDIT2**: some skeleton code:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("tools")
@Stateless
public class RESTTools {

@EJB
private CatalogueLocal catalogue;

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    logger.debug("Initializing REST client");
}
}

@Stateless
@Local(CatalogueLocal.class)
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class Catalogue {

@PostConstruct
public void initialize() {
    logger.debug("Initializing catalogue");
}

}
```

Comment: May be skeleton of code help in understanding the issue. Otherwise it is shooting in dark.

Comment: Since a Stateless bean should have no state, you shouldn't iniitialize it at all. If you are doing it, you are probably misusing something. By the way, RESTTools is a REST service, not a REST client

Comment: You are right, the logging is off :) Anyway, it seems I will have to alter/scrap the cache then.

Comment: You are confusing stateful and stateless beans. If the bean needs to be initialized it should be stateful and those are indeed constructed and destroyed on demand (unlike stateless beans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have misinterpretted the lifecycle.

Stateless beans are instantiated as needed and are activated from an instance pool by the container.

Comment: Does this mean the stateless bean is never destroyed? Or something like gc: in theory it is but you can't count on it?

Comment: That's up to the container.  I suggest googling/reading about it.